# Escaping user input necessary if using json_encode?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

If I take some input from a user in `$_POST` and json_encode it

```
$json = json_encode($_POST);
```

and put it in the query

```
$save = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table (json) VALUES ('$json')");
```

Is this prone to SQL injection? Does this input needs to be escaped? In my tests, I couldn't run any queries with input like

```
') SELECT * FROM table; --
```

but I'm not even remotely good at this.

PS - This is a test for learning. I'm not actually doing this in a project.

Comment: Why take the risk - just use prepared statements every time you get worried about this and let the api/database take care of it.

Comment: never escape anything. Just use prepared statements 100% of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, yes it is vulnerable. `json_encode()` does not escape special characters except for `"`.

Here's a demo:

```
<?php
$a = [ "name" => "O'Reilly" ];
$j = json_encode($a);
echo "$j\n";
```

Output:

```
{"name":"O'Reilly"}
```

Now what would happen if you interpolated this into an SQL string?

You'd get an unescaped single-quote character inside a single-quoted SQL string literal, which causes a syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO table (json) VALUES ('{"name":"O'Reilly"}')
                                            ^
```

The advice in the comments above is correct: When in doubt, use query parameters. Then you don't have to worry about whether the string is safe.